# CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN cannot be resolved or is not a field Error

Tags: java

My code is below, I am getting this error:

> CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN cannot be resolved or is not a field Error

Can anybody help me here?

```
private static String parseCellAsString(Cell cell) {
        String val = null;
        if (cell != null) {
            switch (cell.getCellType()) {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                val = cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "";
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                val = new BigDecimal(cell.getNumericCellValue()).toPlainString();
                break;              
            default:
                val = cell.getStringCellValue();
                break;
            }
        }
        return val;
    }
```

Comment: is your `import` correct for `Cell`?

Answer (score 4):

If you're using a later version of Apache POI, `Cell.getCellType()` returns the [`CellType`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellType.html) enum instead of `int`, so your switch should look like this:

```
switch (cell.getCellType()) {
    case BOOLEAN:
        // ...
    case NUMERIC:
        // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use unqualified names when switching over enums.

```
case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
```

should simply be

```
case CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
```